WiX XML Always modifies the first element in my .config, ignoring the key property
I am trying to understand Wix, but I can't properly modify my .config file. Here is an example:
<configuration>
 <configSections>
<!--All custom Sections must be delcared here-->
   <section name="settings" type="System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection"/>
 </configSections>
   <settings>
    <add key="DatabaseServer" value="localhost"/>
    <add key="DatabaseName" value="SampleDB"/>
  </settings>
</configuration>

And I want to modify DatabaseName in my wix project like this:
<Component Id="ModifyConfig" >
<File Id="AppConfigFile" Source="..path\to\my.config" KeyPath="yes" />
<util:XmlFile Id="SetAppSetting"
              File="[#AppConfigFile]"
              Action="setValue"
              ElementPath="/configuration/settings/add[key='DatabaseName']"
              Name="value"
              Value="somethingElse" />
</Component>

Also tried with @key.
However, I only manage to modify the first value (DatabaseServer). I am pretty sure it has something to do with the key property not being properly resolved, yet chatGPT and a quick google search show me no different approach than what I've already been doing.
How do i modify the DatabaseName instead?

You need to escape square brackets (and use @key):
<util:XmlFile
   ElementPath="/configuration/settings/add[\[]@key='DatabaseName'[\]]"
/>

The problem with unescaped [xxx] is that these fragments are pre-processed (see Formatted) and replaced by MSI before being passed to the XmlFile action. So in your case what is passed to the extension is /configuration/settings/add (resolves to the first element)

Sorry for the long wait. If I am using any other format, It not only doesn't work, but also throws an error. I've already tried with @key and also with escaping the brackets exactly as shown (I currently use Wix v5, if that matters), but to no avail.  (I can add an image to my original post if you don't believe me) I've also checked my ElementPath using online xml tools, which give me the correct node.
I have given up on the xmlfile in wix and instead use custom actions now

@Azzarrel Sorry wrong example. Escaping is MSI is not just \] but [\]]. Updated the answer. That's one weird way of escaping, but that's it.
